# Subcategory route mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi im having a problem to figure this out, i am literally going nuts. I got a scenario like this. Category , Category-SubCategory, Category-SubCategory-SubSubCategory

I cant for the life of me figure out this route. My last and current is like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Navigation", 
            "Navigation/{nav}/{sub}/{subsub}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Site", nav = UrlParameter.Optional, sub = UrlParameter.Optional, subsub = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I figure like this that UrlParameter.Optional would skip the sub or the subsub but instead it puts system.UrlParameter.Optional as a parameter there. Any ideas on how this can be handled?

**EDIT 1:**
so far i limited the site with 2 sub categories and did 3 routes and 3 actionresults. not a pretty solution but works for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut it to one route by cheating a bit.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "navigation",
            "{nav}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Page", nav = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and i write all the categories, subcategories in the nav like

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Page", "Navigation", new { nav = "Category/Sub/", name = "Name" }, null)%>
```

i figure the {nav} dont really got any function here except to show the category path and in case i need to break it out ill use the string spliter.

Answer (score 1):

That's a scenario you cannot have. You can have only a single optional parameter in your route definition and this parameter should always be the LAST parameter in your route. Otherwise the routing engine cannot disambiguate between the routes and this rule has been enforced in ASP.NET MVC 3. This means that `nav`, `sub` and `subsub` cannot be optional. You need to always provide a value for those parameters.

Consider the following urls:

```
Navigation/1
Navigation/1/2
```

It's impossible to say without ambiguity to which of your route parameters to bind `1` and `2`.

Comment: What are my options? is there a other way? It cant be that sub categories/pages cant be done with MVC, it a pretty common thing on ie a webshop even on a regular site

Comment: @Dejan, you cannot handle those in the route. You could use query string parameters, for example: `Navigation?nav=1&subsub=2`.

Comment: Ok, querystring url is not a option on this site. I just found something like Navigation/{*sub}, i need to explore that more tho. oh maybe that is the querysting option?

Comment: @Dejan, what you are trying to do is not possible. Consider the following url: `Navigation/a/b`. Can you tell from it if `nav="a", sub="b", subsub=""`, or `nav="", sub="a", subsub="b"`, or `nav="a", sub="", subsub="b"`? You can't. The routing engine neither. What you refer to `Navigation/{*sub}` is called a catch-all route meaning that you could have the following controller action `public ActionResult Foo(string sub) { ... }` and inside this action `sub="1/2"` but you still won't be able to disambiguate your routes. So I would recommend you rethinking what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: How would you do in this situation when you got sub categories?

Comment: @Dejan, see my second comment about query string parameters where you can have many optional values. That's how I would do it. Of course if you enforce the rule that those values are not optional you could perfectly fine haver a route is you wish.

Comment: ok. thanks for comments. it kinda su*** doing querystring parameters, im not gone do it. ill rethink my sititation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use separate quesy string parameters than use a single category parameter in your route and pass multiple values comma-separated.

For example, an url **/Navigation/1,2,,3**

will translate to an action with one string parameter 'category' which you can than split by comma to get:

```
category: 1
sub-cat: 2
sub-sub-cat: empty
sub-sub-sub-cat: 3
```

This will allow you to change the number of subcategories without redefining your routing.

PS. Instead of comma you might want to use other character that won't be used in category names'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Darin that you might want to think a little more about your architecture, but I believe this series of routes would work for you:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Navigation", 
    "Navigation/{nav}/{sub}/{subsub}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Site", nav = "", sub = "", subsub = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Navigation", 
    "Navigation/{nav}/{sub}/{subsub}", 
    new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Site", nav = "", sub = "", subsub = UrlParameter.Optional, id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Navigation", 
    "Navigation/{nav}/{sub}", 
    new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Site", nav = "", sub = UrlParameter.Optional, subsub = "", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Navigation", 
    "Navigation/{nav}", 
    new { controller = "Navigation", action = "Site", nav = UrlParameter.Optional, sub = "", subsub = "", id = "" }
);
```